# How to disable bracket autocomplete in Spyder?

Tags: python, macos, editor, spyder

How do you turn off the bracket autocomplete feature in Spyder? I'm using Spyder 4.0.1 on OS X Mojave.

Consider the following Python dictionary:

`data_desired = {'Year': [],`
                `'Number of tropical storms': [],`
                `'Number of hurricanes': [],`
                `'Number of Major Hurricanes': [],`
                `'Deaths': [],`
                `'Damage': []}`

Writing this out in Spyder, I often get:

`data_desired = {'Year': []],`

and need to go back and fix the extra bracket.

Regardless of whether the autocomplete feature works well or not, auto-bracketing does not help me because I have to right arrow past the newly generated bracket anyway, which slows down typing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `Tools >> Preferences >> Editor >> Advanced Settings >> Untick "Automatic insertion of parentheses, braces and brackets"`
Then `Apply >> OK`.

[image]

## Update: Spyder 5.x

This option was moved to `Tools >> Preferences >> Editor >>` **Source Code** `>> Untick "Automatic insertion of parentheses, braces and brackets"`
Then `Apply >> OK`.

[image]